# ISO7816.SW_BYTES_REMAINING_00 return 9000 status in javacard

Tags: javacard

I have a problem that confused me for couple of day.
I want to send out a data with size bigger than 255 bytes from smartcard to host application.
I saw a block of code in some website. this code is like bellow:

```
private void sendData(APDU apdu) {
        // work out how many bytes to send this time and how many will be left
        BUF_IN_OFFSET[0] = 0;

        short remain = (short) ((short)372 - BUF_IN_OFFSET[0]);
        boolean chain = remain > MAX_APDU;
        short sendLen = chain ? MAX_APDU : remain;
        Util.arrayCopy(data, (short) 0, apdu.getBuffer(), (short) 0, sendLen);
        // Get ready to send
        apdu.setOutgoing();
        apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)sendLen);
        apdu.sendBytesLong(apdu.getBuffer(), BUF_IN_OFFSET[0], sendLen);

         // Check to see if there are more APDU's to send
        if (chain) {
            BUF_IN_OFFSET[0] += sendLen; // count the bytes sent
            remain -=sendLen;
            ISOException.throwIt((short)((ISO7816.SW_BYTES_REMAINING_00) + remain));

        } else {
            BUF_IN_OFFSET[0] = 0; // no more bytes to send
        }


    }
```

When i send apdu to the card in netbeans simulator, it send 6100 correctly. but when i send it to real card (smartcafe 3.2) card. it send for me 9000. it means in simulator it works but by real card it doesn't work.
I guess it related to protocol T=0 or T=1.
I didn't find any code for T=1. above code is for T=0.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to let the host application keep state about the offset? (I.e. provide a `GET LENGTH` instruction, and a `READ BINARY` instruction with offset parameter.)

Comment: In some cases your comment is true, for example when you want stream of bytes. but in some cases applet does everything for example reading an object which generated on card.

Answer (score 0):

'6100' sounds like a contradiction in the terms. It tells the reader to fetch some data, with lengh available being naught. I believe the real card will actually turn this into a 9000 which is the proper execution status code when no data is available.

Comment: thanks for reply takumar. I agree with you if there is no data available in card, but i have more data. according to above code all of data is stored in data variable with length 372 bytes. I read 255 bytes in first command and send (ISO7816.SW_BYTES_REMAINING_00 + remained bytes) to host to say that there is more data and how much it's length. then host send get response commands to read remain data.

Comment: Why not simply send the whole data block to the card OS to manage, and let it generate 61xx codes for you ? In my opinion this should not have to be coded at application level, because it is a common transport mechanism.

Comment: Do you mean i send whole 372 byte in response apdu follow below code:   apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)372);   apdu.sendBytesLong(data, (short) 0, (short)372);   but I try this before and it didn't work and send 6F00 status word.